# How an application can intercept all firebase pushes coming to an android device

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification

The task of the application is to save all firebase pushes.

How can I make my application intercept all incoming firebase pushes on an android device?

Is it possible on a device without root access?
Is it possible to do it at all?

Thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

There is no documented way for an Android application to intercept messages that the device receives through Firebase Cloud Messaging.

For your own application you can use the [documented API to receive messages](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive), but there's nothing to do so for all apps (as that'd be a big security risk).

---

Even for FCM messages sent by/to your own application, consider if the reliability and observability with which your code gets executed is enough to meet your goals and requirements.

For example, most applications that I know of store the messages they send in a cloud-hosted database too, and load them from there when the app starts.

This ensures they can track whether the message was read by their app (and its user) even in cases where FCM may not have been able to deliver the message (in time), or where they have no way to capture whether the user has seen the notification.